# Grouping values inside a list

Tags: python, group-by

Given this list:

```
['IND', 'MIA', '06:37 AM', '103', 'LA', 'SUN', '06:49 AM', '-150', '120']
```

I would like to group (make tuples) the list for the net result of:

```
[('IND', 'MIA', '06:37 AM', '103'), ('LA', 'SUN', '06:49 AM', '-150', '120')]
```

Meaning a group is a list of values that starts with a word (there will always be 2 consecutive words actually), here: `IND` followed by some other values up to another word, here: `LA`. It is possible that all the word pairs will be idential e.g. this will be valid list:

```
['IND', 'MIA', '06:37 AM', '103', 'IND', 'MIA', '06:49 AM', '-150', '120']
```

it also needs to be grouped. Can you provide some neaty solution please?

Comment: What defines a word?  Always alphabetic, with no spaces or numbers?

Comment: Will there always be just 4 values that need to be put in each tuple?

Comment: @DSM always letters, no spaces nor numbers; NightHallow: no, the number of values will vary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking the assumptions:

- Words are alphabetic strings only
- A block starts with k words, k>=1 (two apparently)
- There are no words in the data portion of the list elements

One way is to group by words and data, then build a list comprehension to join the pairs:

```
import itertools as it
data = ['IND', 'MIA', '06:37 AM', '103', 'LA', 'SUN', '06:49 AM', '-150', '120']
g = it.groupby(data, str.isalpha)
[tuple(v)+tuple(next(g)[1]) for _, v in g]
```